# Bind ctrl+space to backspace

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to make <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> shortcut do a backspace. I can run a command, but is there a way or a program that emulate directly the key pressed?

Comment: Have you tried with `stty erase -yourcodehere-`? For instance `stty erase ^?` will make the back space the key to erase characters `stty erase p` will make letter p erase characters and so on.

Comment: In what environment: in X11 (i.e. in the GUI)? In a terminal (which?)?

Answer (score 0):

The point of the question appears to be asking if some use is already being made for this key combination.

Some terminals use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> to activate an input method.  Here are a few comments/examples:

- [CTRL-Space always toggles Chinese IME (Windows 7)](https://superuser.com/questions/327479/ctrl-space-always-toggles-chinese-ime-windows-7)
- [“ctrl+space” has been bound to invoke some input method and does not work in Emacs or Eclipse auto-complete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243639/ctrlspace-has-been-bound-to-invoke-some-input-method-and-does-not-work-in-ema)
- [Ctrl-Space doesn't change the input method #53](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/text-app/issues/53)